# connection resets when using set_configuration in PyUSB

Tags: android, python-2.7, libusb, pyusb, android-open-accessory

I've recently updated my android phone to Marshmallow. Unfortunately for me, that broke my python code.

using PyUSB, I can get the device to enter accessory mode. Unfortunately, I can no longer read/write to the device, as now using `set_configuration()` resets the connection, causing the device to exit accessory mode and re-enter MTP mode.

```
dev = list(usb.core.find(find_all=True))[0]
dev.ctrl_transfer(0xc0,51,data_or_wLength=2)
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40,52,wIndex=0,data_or_wLength='SAMSUNG')
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40,52,wIndex=1,data_or_wLength='SAMSUNG_Android')
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40,52,wIndex=2,data_or_wLength='16DIGITSERIALNUM')
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40,52,wIndex=3,data_or_wLength='AOA')
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40,52,wIndex=4,data_or_wLength='Whatever')
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40,52,wIndex=5,data_or_wLength='4')
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40,53)
time.sleep(5)
dev = list(usb.core.find(find_all=True))[0]
dev.set_configuration() ## Aaaaaand we're back to MTP...
```

I can't find any way around this; no references to this problem. Only solution I can some up with is to learn C and use `libusb` directly, assuming the `PyUSB` module is to blame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this isn't a good solution, but just in case anyone else just happens to come across this problem and find this:

The problem is with the specific backend (`libusb0`), which sends a message to reset configuration or something like that if an interface is already claimed. In some devices (mine, for example), this causes a programmatic reset of the connection.

My workaround involves using the`libusb1` backend when re-acquiring the device in accessory mode, since it doesn't cause a reset. But since `libusb1` won't let me do control transfers, I need to switch between backends.

`from usb.backend import libusb0, libusb1`, and then `be0,be1 = libusb0.get_backend(),libusb1.get_backend()`.

Then just specify the backend as a parameter to `usb.core.find`

Comment: im having a similar problem, and this post seems to have spotted my exact problem. only issue is, i can't seem to figure out how to install libusb1 on my windows to get past this. all instructions ive seen seem to generate the libusb0.dll (using libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0). any guidance here?

Comment: @KKP I tried 2 libusb-s (probably libusb0 and libusb1, I think that was the numbering). From what I recall, one had alot of tools, one of which was used to register devices so they can be later detected, and one was just a dll I had to copy and paste it to a place where the search path will find it (iirc, same folder as the python interpreter did the trick). That's all I remember, and I don't have access to the backup of that computer atm :;/ good luck!